# The yogic or tantric significance of devi mahatmya

Tags: scripture, devi, durga

What is the yogic or tantric significance of the Durga Saptashati or the devi mahatmya?

Specifically, the devi mahatmya *prima facie*  seems to be about the qualities of devi and her confrontations with the asuras Madhu-Kaitubha, Mahishasura, Raktabija, Dhoomralochana, Shumbha-Nishumbha and her eventual victory. But, what is the inner import of the hymn?